# How to bind ComboBox value to the TextBox value

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

I want to bind the `ComboBox` value upto the `TextBox` value. Here is an example:

Let's say I have one `TextBox` and one `ComboBox`

Now in `TextBox` there is value of 5. So as per the `TextBox` value is 5 my `ComboBox` would be bind upto 5 and in the list of `ComboBox` it would be saw the number upto 5 i.e. 1,2,3,4,5.

Same if the `TextBox` contain the value 3 then as per the change of `TextBox` value on the spot `ComboBox` should be bind upto the `TextBox` value.

I am working on it also but there is some list error.

Here is my code:

```
List<string> hafta = new List<string>();
hafta.Add(txt_hafta.Text);
for (int i = 0; i <= hafta.Count; i++)
{
    cmb_hafta.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
    cmb_hafta.DataSource = hafta[i];
    cmb_hafta.DisplayMember = i.ToString();
}
```

I am not sure that this code is perfect.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @waka I am getting this error "Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource." in the "cmb_hafta.DataSource = hafta[i];" line of code. But I dont think so this code is perfect.

Comment: its cmb_hafta.DataSource = hafta; instead of hafta[i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On TextBox text changed:

```
int count = 0;
Int32.TryParse(txt_hafta.Text, out count);
List<int> dataSource = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    dataSource.Add(i);
}

hafta.DataSource = dataSource;
hafta.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about binding, then you can bind `ComboBox.DataSource` property to `TextBox.Text` property with custom eventhandler for `Binding.Format` event, where you can "convert" string to collection of numbers.

Put code below in the constructor of your form.

```
var binding = 
    new Binding("DataSource", txt_hafta, "Text", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
binding.Format += (sender, args) =>
{
    int.TryParse(args.Value.ToString(), out int maxNumber);
    args.Value = Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumber).ToList();
};

cmb_hafta.DataBindings.Add(binding);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
        List<string> hafta = new List<string>();
        int total = Int32.Parse(txt_hafta.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i <= total ; i++)
        {
            hafta.Add(i.ToString());                 

        }
        cmb_hafta.DataSource = hafta;
```